# Where can i find a list of couchdb apps?

Tags: couchdb, couchapp, kanso

I already know http://www.couchapp.org/page/list-of-couchapps. 
I can't find a list of kanso made apps or even reupholster apps and i bet there are more.
Shouldn't there be a site with all the apps that run on couchdb?

Comment: i hope [this list](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CouchDB_in_the_wild) is useful.

Comment: it has a lot of interesting stuff but not many pure couchapps.i need more javascript centric apps (or at most python dependent apps.).Anyway the link shows the potential of couchdb.

Comment: [10 javascript couchdb apps](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/standalone.html) I cant really find a lenghty list of javascript apps.

Answer (score 3):

Try http://garden20.com/market

All of the apps there should also have a link to their source code. All currently are kanso apps. The list is no way exhaustive, but should give you a good start into making couchapps.

Disclaimer, I have written garden20 to make couchapps easier to install for end users.